# XCODE 5 - Storyboard Segues Push vs Modal

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am currently learning iOS development and I began with a simple Tabbed Application. It has the default First and Second View in it. I added a TableView with static cells content. I then added another View Controller. I created a Segue using the storyboard. When I set the transition to modal, it works fine. When I set it to push, the app is crashing (Uncaught exception).

1. Any idea why?
2. How can I get more information regarding the exception? Can I make the app stops when it encounters an exception?

Comment: You can add an all exception breakpoint. Some exception log should appear in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.. I need to add a Navigation Controller to use push...